# What other Design Languages Exist?

Tags: web

Im really into Web Design techniques and skills and I would like to know what other Design Languages Exist?

I only know two:
Material Design (Google) 
Metro Design (Microsoft)

I would like to practice them all..

Thank you

Comment: "A Pattern Language: Towns, Buildings, Construction" by Christopher Alexander https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Pattern_Language

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple that come to mind:

[Google's Material Design Guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html)

[Apple's iOS 8 Flat Design Guidelines](https://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/design/)

[Microsoft's Metro Design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465424.aspx)

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) (not necessarily a design language, but it does have its own 'style')

[Oracle Alta UI](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/ux/middleware/alta/index.html)

[GNOME Human Interface](https://developer.gnome.org/hig/stable/)

[General Design Guidelines for the Modern World](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/03/23/best-practices-in-modern-web-design-the-ultimate-round-up/)

Some extra hints on how to go about designing [here](http://www.liquidplanner.com/blog/designing-better-software-5-rules-to-follow/).

The most popular ideas today are flat designs, vibrant colors, and smooth animations.